# JavaScript array of objects conversion

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, orm

I wasnt exactly sure what i should name this question so feel free to edit the title.

I am running an angular application and using `node.js` combinded with `express` and `sequlize` (for my `ORM`)

Now as many of you may know when your working with an `ORM` you want to collect `Objects` inside of another `Object` for instance a `user` object might have a `country` object inside of it as shown below:

```
user = {id: 222, username: 'Marc', name: 'Marc Ras', country: {id: 1, code: 'DK', name: 'Denmark'}}
```

Now this is great. binding all of these objects together makes it alot easier to work with  in the frontend.

However the  other way around is rather annoying.

Lets for the purpose of demonstration take the above object. but lets add a `property` an `array of items`

```
user.items = [{id: 1 , name:'item1'}, {id: 2, name: 'item2'}]
```

Now if i wish to add this object to my database i would send the combined object to my express route:

```
var user = {
    id: 222,
    username: 'Marc',
    name: 'Marc Ras',
    country: {id: 1, code:'DK', name: 'Denmark'}
    items: [
        {id: 1, name: 'item1'},
        {id: 2, name: 'item2'}
    ]
}
```

And now things get abit messy

Say for instance you have the following table:

```
user_has_items
```

Each record in this has an `id`, `user_id`, `item_id`

Now in order to make sure that the objects inside `user.items` match the table you will now have to make code gymnastic by making loops and editing the above object.

Like as such:

```
user.items.forEach(function (x) {
    x.item_id = x.id;
    x.id =  null; // To make sure the database does not set the id (since this is auto inc)
    x.user_id = user.id;
})
```

*Note the above is of course an example it gets more complicated the bigger your object is!*

This process leads to messy code (atleast in my opinion) and since this is not the first time i encounter this problem i was wondering if any of you had any solutions as to what you might do to make this process easier?

I have been looking at [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) to see if they had some way of doing this but sadly i could not find anything that made this easy

Comment: You should add the code you've attempted to make your question clearer - _"you will now have to make code gymnastic by making loops and editing the above object"_ isn't clear, for example.

Comment: @Andy i agree il add it to my question

Comment: @Andy added some code :)

Comment: Are you looking to restructure the items array on the user object to your desired format or create a new array of objects?